# Incorrect audit in Low Quality Posts: link-only post, while audit insist on the fact it is OK

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits

I encountered [the following review audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/29454582) (on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68190959/2452869)) in the Low Quality Posts Review Queue.

I marked this post to be Recommended for Deletion with a standard "This is a link-only answer" reason...and failed an audit.

- I don't believe, that this answer is anything more than a link
- The link description matches EXACTLY the title of the question, not adding any insight
- The condensed version of the information from the link could be potentially added to the answer to actually make it valuable. In the current form, it deserves to be a comment.

Please, consider removing this post from the list of audits.

Comment: The post has only upvotes, hence why it's considered "good". Downvoting it would remove it being eligible for audit.

Comment: It's annoying when a link-only answer gets upvotes... clearly it was genuinely useful to some (hence the votes), but the answer post itself contains *zero* information. This was definitely a terrible audit; I'm not sure what the best thing to do about the post is in these cases.

Comment: @zcoop98 downvote it at a minimum.

Comment: @VLAZ True; it looks like there's some more guidance in the [NAA FAQ post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-not-an-answer/265553) too, in the section below "links to an answer".

Comment: I've voted to reopen because Meta questions about *specific* audits (especially poor ones) are seldom duplicates (unless there's another question about the *same* audit). In this case, the suggested duplicate is not even similar to the one in this case.

Comment: The post has been deleted by a moderator, so it will  no longer be part of the audit pool.

Comment: @yivi As I stated earlier, the audit in the duplicate you linked has little similarity to the one herein discussed. Audits are a *vital* part of the review system, and **bad** audits need to be reported quickly, here on Meta (so that they can be removed from the audit pool). Closing questions like this as dupes is, IMHO, giving a very wrong signal to other users who happen across such bad audits.

Comment: @AdrianMole I had read what you stated earlier. I still think the dupe applies.

Comment: @yivi would you say that this dup applies to ANY disputed audit post then?

Comment: No, I wouldn’t say that. But I think it applies fairly often. Nothing bad with the question, simply that the dupes explains why it happens and  what to do to remove bad audits from the audit pool.